# Clean/Setup/Run iOS Project - ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency

Tags: react-native, gradle-dependencies

I’m working with a MacBook Pro M2 on an React Native app project and I’m having ‘ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency’ error that is preventing me to run the app. I’m hours and hours trying several different stuff, but still stuck in this error. Anyone able to help me? Follow bellow the error:

dudibarros@Eduardos-MBP BrinkaKids % npm install
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: @callstack/react-theme-provider@3.0.3
npm WARN Found: react@18.2.0
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN   react@"^18.0.0" from the root project
npm WARN   30 more (@react-native-community/clipboard, ...)
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer react@"^16.3.0" from @callstack/react-theme-provider@3.0.3
npm WARN node_modules/@callstack/react-theme-provider
npm WARN   @callstack/react-theme-provider@"3.0.3" from react-native-country-picker-modal@2.0.0
npm WARN   node_modules/react-native-country-picker-modal
npm WARN
npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: react@16.14.0
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN   peer react@"^16.3.0" from @callstack/react-theme-provider@3.0.3
npm WARN   node_modules/@callstack/react-theme-provider
npm WARN     @callstack/react-theme-provider@"3.0.3" from react-native-country-picker-modal@2.0.0
npm WARN     node_modules/react-native-country-picker-modal
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: @react-native-community/async-storage@1.12.1
npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^18.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@">=16.0" from @react-native-community/clipboard@1.5.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/@react-native-community/clipboard
npm ERR!     @react-native-community/clipboard@"^1.5.1" from the root project
npm ERR!   29 more (@react-native-community/push-notification-ios, ...)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.8" from @react-native-community/async-storage@1.12.1
npm ERR! node_modules/@react-native-community/async-storage
npm ERR!   @react-native-community/async-storage@"^1.6.2" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@16.14.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@"^16.8" from @react-native-community/async-storage@1.12.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/@react-native-community/async-storage
npm ERR!     @react-native-community/async-storage@"^1.6.2" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! /Users/dudibarros/.npm/_logs/2023-11-27T00_38_26_075Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /Users/dudibarros/.npm/_logs/2023-11-27T00_38_26_075Z-debug-0.log
dudibarros@Eduardos-MBP BrinkaKids % npm install  --legacy-peer-deps

> SlothWorld@0.0.1 postinstall
> patch-package

patch-package 6.5.1
Applying patches...

**ERROR** Failed to apply patch for package react-native at path

```
node_modules/react-native
```

This error was caused because react-native has changed since you
made the patch file for it. This introduced conflicts with your patch,
just like a merge conflict in Git when separate incompatible changes are
made to the same piece of code.

Maybe this means your patch file is no longer necessary, in which case
hooray! Just delete it!

Otherwise, you need to generate a new patch file.

To generate a new one, just repeat the steps you made to generate the first
one.

i.e. manually make the appropriate file changes, then run

```
patch-package react-native
```

Info:
Patch file: patches/react-native+0.71.3.patch
Patch was made for version: 0.71.3
Installed version: 0.72.7

---

patch-package finished with 1 error(s).

up to date, audited 1764 packages in 6s

133 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details

18 vulnerabilities (5 moderate, 6 high, 7 critical)

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
npm audit fix

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.

I tried clean and reinstall dependencies several times and in several different ways.

I'm expecting to run the project in my computer in both iOS and Android simulators.